# Why does PHP called with Jquery AJAX not allow additional php code to be added?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I wrote a plugin a few years ago that successfully uses AJAX and then recently I tried to add more of the same functionality but it fails.  In the PHP files,

1. I localized admin-ajax into the JQuery script:
   `wp_localize_script( 'cp_script', 'cp_script', new array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), ) );`
2. I added the ajax action:
   `add_action( 'wp_ajax_chatpress_erase_all_messages', new array( $this, 'chatpress_erase_all_messages' ) );`
3. I wrote the php function that is fired:

```
public function chatpress_erase_all_messages() {
        wp_send_json_success( [
            'message' => 'foobar',
        ] );

    }
```

then in the JQuery, I wrote a function to actually call the code:

```
    $('#erase-old').on( 'click', function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "post",
            dataType : "json",
            url : cp_script.ajaxurl,
            data : { action: "chatpress_erase_all_messages" },
            success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
            }
         });

        
      
    });
```

The request on the network tab looks like:
[image]

whenever I test, the output is the success message.  This is a new feature that is similar to the old one which has been working.  When I add any other code to the PHP function `chatpress_erase_all_messages()`, I stop getting the success back and the code does not fire (echo, print_r, wp_die, nothing).  I thought I replicated the same steps as with other, similar features but no. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong/why the output is nothing when I actually add code to the PHP function before what is shown above?

Comment: 1. Your JS is expecting a JSON response, so did your "other code" send/output a valid JSON data (and header)? 2. Note that you can't echo anything if your function is (still) calling `wp_send_json_success()`, e.g. don't do `echo 'foo'; wp_send_json_success();`

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab of the developer tools? What's the actual response?

Comment: @SallyCJ no, the "other code" was `echo "test";` and `print_r('test');` how would I use the other code to send/output a valid JSON data (and header)?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: Well that shows there's nothing wrong with the code you've shared, as you've mentioned, and there's no technical reason in PHP or WordPress why just 'any other code' would stop a function from working, so the issue must be with the actual code you're adding, so you're going to need to share that to get any more help. Otherwise all I can do is recommend checking your error logs.

Comment: @JacobPeattie ok it all works now, it was the fact that `echo` and `print_r` and `wp_die()` don't work on an AJAX call that got me.  If I query the database before the `wp_send_json_success()` then the query works.  One thing though, do you know what @SallyCJ meant by "if your function is *still* calling `wp_send_json_success()`? Is there a new way to do it or something?

Comment: Those functions work fine for AJAX. The problem is that if you’re also using wp_send_json_ then you’re mixing up other output with JSON meaning that the response is not valid JSON. That’s what Sally was talking about.